# Rest API requests failing in Airflow ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Tags: python-requests, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm requesting data through a rest API using the requests library. Everything works locally, but when I deploy to my GCP composer instance I experience errors.

```
def get_ids():
    s = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[429])
    s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

    ids = []
    counter = 0
    url = "some_url"  + "/?limit=50"

    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = r.json()

    for i in data['items']:
        if 'custom' in i['user']:
            ids(i['user']['custom']['id'])

    while 'next' in  data['_links']:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        try:
            r = s.get("some url"+  data['_links']['next']['href'], headers=headers)
            data = r.json()
            counter+=1
            for i in data['items']:
                if 'custom' in i['user']:
                    try:
                        ids(i['user']['custom']['accountId'])
                    except KeyError:
                        pass
            
    return ids
```

Runs on my local machine, but this is the error I get running in airflow/composer:

```
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,041] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,053] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,066] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     httplib_response = self._make_request(
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,074] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,082] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     six.raise_from(e, None)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,092] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,111] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,118] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,136] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,146] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     response.begin()
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,160] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,180] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,192] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 277, in _read_status
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,214] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,224] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,243] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     return self._sock.recv_into(b)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,252] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,274] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,281] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,301] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,322] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,330] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - 
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,350] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,359] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - 
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,379] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,386] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,406] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     resp = conn.urlopen(
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,416] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,436] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     retries = retries.increment(
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,443] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,463] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,469] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,490] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,518] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,539] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     httplib_response = self._make_request(
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,575] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,578] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     six.raise_from(e, None)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,594] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,621] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,639] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,675] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1348, in getresponse
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,683] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     response.begin()
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,700] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,707] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,727] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 277, in _read_status
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,735] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,755] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,763] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     return self._sock.recv_into(b)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,782] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,803] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,906] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,913] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,927] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,930] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - 
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,932] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,937] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - 
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,940] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,943] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "my_script.py", line 114, in <module>
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,945] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     main(api_key, environment)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,946] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "my_script.py", line 95, in main
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,950] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     ids = get_ids()
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,953] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "my_script.py", line 39, in get_ids_ids
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,954] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     r = s.get("some url", headers=headers)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,956] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in get
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,958] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,964] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,966] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,966] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,967] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,969] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,972] {subprocess.py:78} INFO -     raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
[2022-05-19 01:43:10,979] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
[2022-05-19 01:43:12,592] {subprocess.py:82} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
[2022-05-19 01:43:13,014] {taskinstance.py:1465} ERROR - Task failed with exception
```

any guidance here? I've tried increasing the sleep, increasing the backoff, but nothing's worked. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm facing the same issue.